# Add subView in storyboard

Tags: ios, view, storyboard, subview

In my program needs to create view, then create subView and add it in view. 
I create view and subView in storyboard. Then in code:

```
[subView removeFromSuperview];
[view addSubview:subView];
[self.view addSubview:view];
```

How can I add subView to view in storyboard without code?

Comment: Drag n drop add subView in self.view but I want in view.

Comment: Drag and drop it on the view, or drop it in the left inspector.

Comment: How open left inspector?)

Comment: ctr+cmd+right arrow, ctrl+cmd+left arrow

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You don't actually need to write any code for this. There are many ways to do this:

1. Select the subview and drag over the view entry in the Objects Explorer of storyboard. Once you leave the mouse hold, the parent view will have a triangle indicating your subview has become its child and the subview will have a bigger indent than your view
2. Or you can use the "Embed in View" menu as shown in the below pic [source:http://codesheriff.blogspot.co.il/2014/03/8-tips-for-working-effectively-with.html]

[image]

Answer (score 3):

open file inspector ->search for view drag and Drop the view in storyboard

[image]

so in this you already holding a view now you adding an view its almost like adding a sub view to the main view this is for adding view without code

Answer (score 0):

Open the storyboard and just create the new view inside the subview.

What your doing above is doing nothing.

```
[subView removeFromSuperview]; //Your removing subview from the superview
[view addSubview:subView]; //is view a new UIView?
[self.view addSubview:view];
```

Comment: view and subView added in self.view. I remove subView from self.view, add it in view and then add view in self.view.

Comment: try this: [subView removeFromSuperview]; 
UIView *aView = [[UIView alloc] init]; [aView addSubview:subView]; 
[self.view addSubview:aView];

Comment: are you kidding me? I want that I can do it. In first post write "without code"

Answer (score -1):

You Will have a View in the bottom of right side.You Just drag and Drop the view Where you Want.To Set constriants clearly We are goin Dynamic view Creation.If you do View creation programmatically it will help you in the future project.

Comment: Could you elaborate? This does not seem to be very clear and precise.

Comment: @Christophe Weis. If we go through the Storyboard,It won't provide design exactly how we want.so only we are writing code dynamically.This is shown clearly in this link http://www.raywenderlich.com/50317/beginning-auto-layout-tutorial-in-ios-7-part-1                        Pls Upvote if it is useful to you..

Comment: Why you gave negative.